# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. -getting this error in automation (using testng,selenium,java)

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-java

```
My files are given below. please help me in parallel execution in same machine. Multiple Browsers are opening  but URL in one browser is not getting added also. and this is what error is coming which is mentioned in output .Thanks in advance.








This is testng file.
-----## testng##-----
    
    
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    
    <suite name="BOC UI AUTOMATION">
        <test name="BOC Feature Testing" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
            <classes>
                <class name="runner.loginPageRunner"></class>
              
                <class name="runner.B2BSmokeRunner"></class>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
    
    
    
    


----------

This is driver settings file where i am selecting driver of browser.
    ## Driversetting ##
    


----------


    package base;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    
    //import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import utils.FileReference;
    
    
    public class DriverSettings
    {
        /**
         * Overloaded browser setup with browser name and time-out being
         * sent as parameter
         * @param browserName : name of the browser (like: firefox, ie, chrome) case insensitive
         * @param timeUnitInSecond : Timeout second for implicit time-out
         */
        public void setUpDriver(String browserName, int timeUnitInSecond)
        {
            final FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            switch(browserName.trim().toLowerCase())
            {
            case "firefox" :
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", FileReference.driversFilePath+File.separator+"geckodriver.exe");
                System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
                options.addPreference("browser.popups.showPopupBlocker", false);
                options.addPreference("security.sandbox.content.level", 5);
                Driver.driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
                break;
    
            case "chrome" :
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", FileReference.driversFilePath+File.separator+"chromedriver.exe");
                HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
                chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", FileReference.download);
                ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
                option.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
                option.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
                Driver.driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
                break;
    
            default : 
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\geckodriver.exe");
                System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
                options.addPreference("browser.popups.showPopupBlocker", false);
                options.addPreference("security.sandbox.content.level", 5);
                Driver.driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
                break;
            }
            setWait(timeUnitInSecond);
            setBrowserAtMaxSize();
        }
    
        /**
         * Sets the implicit time out as parameter
         * @param timeUnitInSecond : Timeout second for implicit time-out
         */
        protected static void setWait(int timeUnitInSecond)
        {
            Driver.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeUnitInSecond, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    
        /**
         * Sets the browser at maximum size of the screen
         */
        protected void setBrowserAtMaxSize()
        {
            Driver.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    
        /**
         * Closes the driver, deletes all cookies
         */
        public void closeDriver()
        {
    //      Driver.driver.close();
            Driver.driver.quit();
        }
    
        public void closeWindow()
        {
            Driver.driver.close();
        }
    }
    


----------


    
    ----------##Driver## ----------
    
    
    package base;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    
    public class Driver
    {
        
        public static WebDriver driver;
    
    }
    
    






    ----------
   ##Browser## 
    
    
    ----------
    package base;
    
    import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException;
    import utils.LoadEnvironment;
    
    public class Browser {
    
        private DriverSettings driverSetting;
        protected static int timeToWait = 30;
    
        public Browser() throws DocumentException
        {
            LoadEnvironment.loadProperties();
            String browserName=LoadEnvironment.browser;
    
            driverSetting = new DriverSettings();
            driverSetting.setUpDriver(browserName, timeToWait);
        }
    
        public Browser(String browserName)
        {
            driverSetting = new DriverSettings();
            driverSetting.setUpDriver(browserName, timeToWait);
        }
    
        public Browser(String browserName, int timeUnitInSecond)
        {
            driverSetting = new DriverSettings();
            timeToWait = timeUnitInSecond;
            driverSetting.setUpDriver(browserName, timeUnitInSecond);
        }
    
        public void close()
        {
            try
            {
                driverSetting.closeDriver();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    
        public static void navigateTo(String URL)
        {
            Driver.driver.get(URL);
        }
    
        public void refresh()
        {
            Driver.driver.navigate().refresh();
        }
    
        /**
         * Read the URL of the current page
         * @return : String URL
         */
        public String getCurrntUrl()
        {
            return Driver.driver.getCurrentUrl();
        }
    
        public static void scrollToBottomOfThePage() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.driver);
            js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
            Thread.sleep(400);
        }
    
        public static boolean isBrowserReachable()
        {
            boolean browserReachable=true;
            try {
                Driver.driver.getTitle();
            }catch(NoSuchSessionException e)
            {
                browserReachable=false;
            }
            return browserReachable;
        }
    
        
    }








----------
##Pom.xml##


----------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>B2BUI_Automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.softwareag</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.4</aspectj.version>
         <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <suite.file>testng.xml</suite.file>
        <browser>chrome</browser>
        <tagsToRun></tagsToRun>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                       -Dcucumber.options="&#45;&#45;plugin utils.CustomCucumberAfterStepListener &#45;&#45;plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm ${tagsToRun}"
                    </argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suite.file}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <browser>${browser}</browser>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}/allure-results</directory></fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resultsDirectory>../allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber4-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

### Output

---

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'SAG-DMPJ622', ip: '10.91.56.203', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.5'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver